# Is it a good practise to store `IsValid` column in a table, for validation?

Tags: mysql

**Goal**

To record room temperatures in MySQL database.

**My 2 scenarios to record the values**

*Scenario 1*

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Room (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Description VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Room (Description) VALUES ('Room 1'), ('Room 2');

CREATE TABLE RoomSpecification (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  RoomId INT NOT NULL,
  MinVal INT,
  MaxVal INT
);

INSERT INTO RoomSpecification (RoomId, MinVal, MaxVal) VALUES
(1, 10, 20),
(2, 20, 30);


CREATE TABLE Records (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  RoomId INT,
  RecordedVal INT,
  IsValid BOOL
);

INSERT INTO Records (RoomId, RecordedVal, IsValid) VALUES
(1 , 20, 1), -- Valid
(2 , 10, 0); -- Not-Valid
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM Records;
```

| Id | RoomId | RecordedVal | IsValid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2xo8siUTjsDcAAEWXJGZby/2)

**Summary**

This scenario includes a column `IsValid`. By using data type `BOOL`, I can recognise that this value is not valid by doing a simple query.

*Scenario 2*

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Room (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Description VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Room (Description) VALUES ('Room 1'), ('Room 2');

CREATE TABLE RoomSpecification (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  RoomId INT NOT NULL,
  MinVal INT,
  MaxVal INT
);

INSERT INTO RoomSpecification (RoomId, MinVal, MaxVal) VALUES
(1, 10, 20),
(2, 20, 30);


CREATE TABLE Records (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  RoomId INT,
  RecordedVal INT
);

INSERT INTO Records (RoomId, RecordedVal) VALUES
(1 , 20), -- Valid
(2 , 10); -- Not-Valid
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    r.*,
    CASE
        WHEN r.RecordedVal BETWEEN MinVal AND MaxVal THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS IsValid
FROM Records r
JOIN RoomSpecification rs ON rs.RoomId = r.Id;
```

| Id | RoomId | RecordedVal | IsValid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h4wRLrt66if41QcNXrNkrh/0)

**Summary**

On the other hand, I have removed the column `IsValid` and used a `query` to do the `Validation`.

**Question**

Between the two scenarios, which would be the correct/good practise scenario to go for? Unless someone else has other suggestions?

Comment: In theory one should not work with invalid data. Processing invalid inputs can produce any output. In practice, sometimes the invalid or incomplete input needs to be stored, in case it can be fixed later. I would not keep it in the same place as the valid data.

Comment: @axiac Regarding your last comment. You'd recommend in having 2 separate tables for `Valid/InValid` records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Scenario 1 is an example of denormalization. This is okay if you really need to make it more optimized to check for a record's validity without doing the join. That is, if you can't tolerate the overhead both in typing the code and executing the code of doing the join to check if each record is valid, as you show in your Scenario 2.

Denormalization is okay. We do this frequently in database design, in cases where we want a short-cut to avoid overhead or extra code.

But keep in mind that denormalization comes with its own cost. The cost is that you have a risk the denormalized data itself will end up being wrong, because it represents a fact that isn't true.

For example, in your Scenario 1, what if someone subsequently updates the data?

```
UPDATE Records SET RecordedVal = 25 WHERE Id = 2;
```

The value they changed is now between the MinVal, MaxVal range for the references room. So this update should have also set IsValid=1, but it didn't. The validity column is now wrong. This is called a *data anomaly.*

Another data anomaly could occur if someone updates the MinValue, MaxValue of a row in the RoomSpecification table. That single update could cause anomalies on thousands of rows or even millions of rows in the Records table.

This is a common risk when you use denormalization. You take on extra work to prevent or at least detect data anomalies. You may have to write more code to ensure updates are forced to update the IsValid column. Maybe you write a trigger to change IsValid if the table is updated. Maybe you write a stored procedure to do the update, and limit update privilege so users must use the procedure. Or maybe you don't prevent anomalies, but you write a scheduled job to search for anomalies that have crept in, and report them.

Whereas if you use Scenario 2, you don't get the convenience of the denormalized design, but you do get the assurance against data anomalies.

Which is best? That's up to you, and the answer could be different for each project, or even for different cases within the same project.

You must use your own judgment based on your knowledge of your own project. This is part of being a professional software engineer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it depends, by storing it into the database bare in mind that you will need to take care of 'IsValid' value if you update temperature stuff.

I always favor to put in the persistence layer only what is really needed, and then calculating `IsValid` when you map from the database into your domain models.

Comment: Lets say the `MinVal & MaxVal` changes in the `RoomSpecification` table. How would you then determine the previous records, whether they are `valid` or not? Because the prev. records should remain as they are.

Comment: Actually this is a good question. I imagine that given that scenario, `IsValid` would be set in a factory whenever you reconstitute your objects for example, by passing current `MinVal` and `MaxVal` somehow. If you want to keep track of the validity of your records whenever were created, you can use EventSourcing techniques, which is really interesting.

I leave you here a interesting post about EventSourcing: https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html

Comment: Thank you pablo - appreciate your helpful information!

Answer (score -3):

If you have no storage issues, I suggest you keep the isValid field for future use. It will be simier to query all valid/invalid data using that.